# Regular Expression for "infinite" URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to create a match for this pattern:

/page/some/thing/is/written/here

where /page is will always match a-zA-Z0-9 and everything after /page can containt the characters a-zA-Z0-9-/
My idea is that "page" always is the page which the user will see, and the rest are parameters, separated by / (p1/p2/p3) etc.

This is what I have come up with: ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)$ 
It works until 3 slashes: page/is/nice

But if I add another parameter like this: page/is/nice/crash
It crashes.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Badly formed or not, regexes shouldn't cause crashes.  Please add some information about what language/software/etc you're using.

Comment: I interpreted "crashes" as meaning it did not match. Maybe I was mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^/?[a-zA-Z]+(/[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

Broken down:

- `^` - lead anchor
- `/?` - it might start with a slash
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more letters
- `(/[A-Za-z0-9]+)*` - zero or more /alphanumerics (with at least one alphanumeric)
- `$` - end anchor

If you have no need to capture the ending, you should use non-capturing groups instead:

```
^/?[a-zA-Z]+(?:/[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

If you want an optional slash at the end, try this:

```
^/?[a-zA-Z]+(?:/[A-Za-z0-9]+)*/?$
```

**Note:** You might have to delimit the slashes depending on your programming language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, gpojd. It still doesn't work. It might be of your interest that I am redirecting within a .htaccess file using rewrite. This is what I've got now: RewriteRule^/?[a-zA-Z]+(?:/[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$ index.php?controller=$1

Comment: hm it should work. using a validator (http://www.sweeting.org/mark/html/revalid.php) it perfectly matches the pattern I want it to.

Comment: Which version of Apache? Some older versions do not support non-matching groups. It worked for in a different regex validator page. I just caught that you use the $1 variable; you will definitely need the capture group - `^/?[a-zA-Z]+(/[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$`.

Comment: @Muncken You don't need half of that in your `.htaccess` : http://pastebin.com/1REFSQWT

Comment: Apache v. 2.2.17. I want to capture the first group, so I have changed it to ^/?([a-zA-Z]+)(/[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$ but it is the same. you can try it out at http://muncken.myftp.org/ensikkersejr

Comment: yoda I have tried your answer as well and the result is the same. use the link I just posted to try it yourself.